# How can I download photorealistic 3D tiles for Cesium JS (React) offline (self hosted)?

Tags: reactjs, download, 3d, cesiumjs, offline-mode

I'm currently working on a project using Cesium to display 3D geospatial data, and I'd like to know if there's a way to download offline city (as paris or New York) photorealistic 3D tiles for Cesium. I want to explore the possibility of accessing these tiles without having to rely solely on a real-time Internet connection.

I've searched Cesium's documentation, but I can't find a clear solution for downloading 3D tiles offline. Has anyone done this before and could they give me some advice or pointers on how to approach this problem?

For example, if we draw an analogy,

For 2D tiles.
I first downloaded these. Tiles, using an Internet connection.

Then I served them using a local http server.
I was therefore able to use the following code:

```
viewerRef.current.scene.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(
      new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
        url: localhost_url,
      })
    );
```

I'd like to do the same, something like:

```
const tileset = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
  url: 'localhost_url',
});
```

To sum up, I'm looking for where I can find his sources, download them and use them.

(I'm mainly looking for open source, but I'm not closed to the idea of looking at paid solutions)